# CCNode-visit-function copied CCSprite got a dark edge

Tags: draw, flatten, ccsprite

I've got a question about the [visit] function of CCNode

The original image is good with clear outline, nothing special, it composes of 5 leaves sprites inside.

SCREEN CAPTURE :

[image: http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6107/6248992365_eab5346264_o.png]

Then I want to use [CCNode visit] to copy it.

And here's the code

```
-(CCSprite *)flattenSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite textureSize:(float)textureSize {

    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:textureSize];
    [rt begin];

    // store the original sprite position
    CGPoint p=sprite.position;
    //set original sprite to a target point for open GL to "visit"
    sprite.position=ccp(textureSize/2,textureSize/2);
    // open GL visit
    [sprite visit];
    //original sprite return to original point
    sprite.position=p;

    [rt end];
    return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
}
```

By this function I can optimize the performance of the application by limiting the amount of the sprites existing on stage but the "copied sprites" got a dark edge around it. It looks weird - especially when the sprites are overlapping each others.

Please tell me if you have any clues / anywhere got useful information about this dark edge issue

Comment: I don't know the answer but I have a hunch it is something to do with blending functions, e.g. you need to have something like [sprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ONE,GL_ONE}];.  I'm still trying to figure out what all the possibilities (GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA, ...) mean though.  I've observed that changing them does affect the edges.

Comment: hi @DanyalAytekin you are right and this question is solved from the following link - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21869 - all the best, kit

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CCSprite *)flattenSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite textureSize:(float)textureSize {

    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureSize height:textureSize];
    [rt begin];

    // store the original sprite position
    CGPoint p=sprite.position;
    //set original sprite to a target point for open GL to "visit"
    sprite.position=ccp(textureSize/2,textureSize/2);
    // open GL visit
    [sprite visit];
    //original sprite return to original point
    sprite.position=p;

    [rt end];

    CCSprite *renderSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
    //this will solve the dark edge problem
    [sprite setBlendFunc: (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }];

    return renderSprite;
}
```